# Socket.emit triggers a new connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, websocket, socket.io

I'm using socket.io in my app, and attaching a socket id to each user after login. I get that info on front end and when I'm trying to emit an event, it creates a new connection so every user gets a new socket id, but the old ids are stored on front end and I'm sending the data to that old ids. What is the solution? (I'm using Angular)

I've tried creating groups, but it really slows down the app because I have to create as many socket groups as every user's friends.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you to solve this problem is to use a unique ID for each user. This unique ID can be created and delivered to the user through rest api. The user puts his ID in an object before every connection to the socket. Your task is this. At the same stage of user connection, create an object for each user. In this object, there are two parameters. The first one is the user ID that does not change, and the second one is the user ID that changes. In this way, you have a list of objects that are inside Each object has two mentioned parameters, it is enough to compare the user using the socket ID loop and implement your logic and operations. Note, at the end of connecting the user, remove the user from the list.

Comment: Yes, I do the same thing, mongoDb creates an id for every user that doesn’t change and on connection i put a socket id in that user document. But when I do an emit() event, a new connection happens and every user gets a new socket id, it doesn’t make sense. And i don’t wanna create groups because it slows down the app.

Comment: @Mikheil I think it's time to share your code